# determine if row is in thead or not jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm sure this is simple with `.parent()` or such but can't find an answer anywhere. I run a function on TR click and I want to determine if that row is in the THEAD or not.

My code:

```
$('.mouseRow tr').click(function() {

   // is this row is in THEAD?

});
```

Comment: is the thead has any class or id so that it can be easily identified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can check the parent, why not?

```
if ($(this).parent("thead").length)
```

Alternatively you couldl've added your event to the row in the head only

```
$('.mouseRow thead tr').click(function() {...});
```

Comment: just a brain fart :). Your second solution is perfect, simple and not adding another line of code

Comment: @themerlinproject I wish you had said that you only wanted to apply to rows in the head. Next time, remember to ask for what you are ultimately trying to do, not for help in doing the random solution you think might work.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.mouseRow tr').click(function() {
   if ($(this).parent().is('thead')){
     // …
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks @phrogz, figured it out right after I posted it. Is .is() the best way to do it? I always kind of think of it as a slow function since it seems to match against so many different properties but that could just be my misconception

Comment: Asking for the "best" way implies that there is some universal fitness criteria for "bestness" that everyone agrees upon. No such criteria exists that I know of. What do you mean by "best"? Is this the absolute fastest (execution) way? Not at all. Is it the least typing? Maybe. Is it easy to use? Yes. That's why I happened to suggest it.

Comment: I generally consider the best to be somewhere in the middle of least code + fastest execution but point taken - how can we really know anything? ;)

Answer (score 0):

alright so I kind of figured it out, but I wonder if this is the best way to do it:

```
if($(this).parent().is("thead"))
```